# extract the keyvalue from array variable cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.0, extract

I have an array that gives me the data like this

```
Array
(
    [5079906a-6eb4] => Selling
)
```

Now I want to use this (5079906a-6eb4) value for my further processing.
My question is how to extract this value from that array variable??

Comment: http://us3.php.net/array_keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to use keys,

```
$keys = array_keys($arr);
```

Or you don't want to lose association,

```
$flipped = array_flip($arr);
```